# MySQL Open Files (MyISAM, Parititioned Large Database)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-partitioning, myisam

I have a quite large database that I am working on, a collection of measurement data.  I am running into issues with hitting the max open files (status global variable **Open_files** hitting the global variable **open_files_limit**).  Sure, I can increase the open_files_limit in /etc/my.cnf, but it seems that I still can't get enough breathing room - heavy user load will ultimately still cause me to hit this condition.

I'm trying to get a better idea as to why so many files are opened, and why they don't seem to close.

**Size Summary**: Total number of tables in the database is approximately 3,000.  *Each table* is using the MyISAM engine, and each table consists of ~500 columns (variable data types) and has 173 partitions.  Each partition represents a week of data.

Table structures (all ~3,000) are each created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_0000` (
  `time_unix` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_msecs` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col_000` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_001` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_002` double DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `col_0501` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time_unix`,`time_msecs`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
 PARTITION BY RANGE (`time_unix`)
(PARTITION `p0` VALUES LESS THAN (1649977029) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION `p1` VALUES LESS THAN (1650581829) ENGINE = MyISAM,
...
 PARTITION `p172` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM)
```

Yes, I know - it's a large amount of data.  MyISAM is being used for fast reading purposes (and transactions are not needed).  This has generally worked extremely well for my setup, it's just when it's getting aggressively/atypically hammered on the reading side that I run into these issues.

My basic questions and observations:

1. If I perform a query like `"SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_0023 WHERE time_unix > 1649977029 AND time_unix < 1650581829;`
   ... **Open_files** increases by 346.  This happens to be [number of partitions]x2, and tells me that this query must be opening each and every partition (both the data file .MYD and the index file .MYI, hence the factor of x2).  This puzzles me, as I would think that I'm only dipping into a single partition (p1) with this query.  Does this have something to do with the composite key versus the partition single-column?  My hunch is that it does, but I'm not sure why.
2. When will these open files begin to close?  It is not clear to me which variable controls this (or if there is one even settable).  I can see that the "offending" user/connection (that performed the query) has no bearing on this ... if they cease to exist the open files remain.  Ideally, I'd like a way to control this (e.g. set it to perhaps an hour).  `FLUSH TABLES;` closes them all, of course, but I gather that this is not intended to be called/used in this manner.

Comment: What does `ulimit -n` (in Ubuntu shell) say?

Comment: How many rows (approx) in each table?  Please show us the query that needs "fast reading".

Comment: ulimit -n shows 1,024,000.  In the case of the above sample query ("COUNT(*)") it doesn't matter if there are zero rows or ten thousand.

Comment: MyISAM never a good sign. Hope this is backed up *frequently*.

Comment: What does "large" amount of data mean here? To the nearest power of ten, like is it 100GB or 100TB? If it's under 100GB it's not "large" in as much as that definition tends to encompass "anything that fits on a single consumer spec drive."

Comment: And 100TB starts to hit some hard limits in MySQL.

Comment: What controls which of the 3000 tables is to be accessed?  And do you need to reach into multiple of the 3000 to get the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for the comments here.  Re the size of the dataset, I guess I was speaking of the relative "dimensions" of the database.  Total size should not exceed maybe 1-2TB in the end (when fully populated), but in the current testing set it is actually empty.

Comment: Re: backing up the MyISAM database, this particular setup is a low-stress dev environment while I'm building application code.  When deployed to a production environment, it is replicated to other servers.

Comment: Re: the 3000 tables ... very good question.  Long story short, there are really about 500 underlying "core" tables.  The other ~2500 are reductions of this core set (e.g. averaging over X minutes or hours).  On the fetching/reading application side, this permits switching resolutions very quickly without overhead (i.e. zooming "out").  So, to answer the question, it's application code that I have written.

Comment: seems to me you've made a lot of choices that have painted you into a corner and it's time to start fresh.  go to an LTS version (10.11 or 10.6), switch to innodb, drop the partitioning, drop the multiple tables with different resolutions (just do this on the fly), use just a datetime(3) type.  reconsider your need for 500 core tables with 300 columns each; this does not sound sane.  start with a sane model and see what performance issues you actually have, asking for help with particular queries

Comment: @ysth , thanks for your assessment of my situation.  I do not disagree - this very much is a database that started small and (due to success) has grown, grown, and grown.  In a nutshell, I have probably 40K different sensors producing data at mostly slow rates (1 Hz), but occasionally fast bursts (ie 100 Hz).  They report at differing times (~500+ in a group report together, all at once).  Hence my decision to cut them into different tables.  Additionally, I anticipate up to 30M records (1 Hz) per year - hence my belief in (vertical) partitions.  What (other than partitions) should I explore?

Comment: so much depends on how you need to query the data.  but I'd certainly start by just trying a datetime(3) primary key (or sensor_group_id+time if you reduce your table count)

Comment: not clear to me what your 30M records are; is each a measurement from 500+ of your 40k sensors?

Comment: So there are approximately 40K sensors.  Previously, I would group them into approximately ~500ish and put them into their own table, as they were being read from the same device (so they all arrive at the exact same time).  Across the 40K, there are different devices reporting at different rates (and varies, depending on interest/activity).  In a completely ideal world, I'd have 40K columns in a single table, and - as these groups/devices report, a row would be added (and null values stored for the other 39.5K columns).  As they probably average to 1 Hz, that's where 30M rows/year comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `table_open_cache` is a "cache".  If it is not big enough, some will be bumped out.
- InnoDB uses fewer file handles.  Assuming `innodb_file_per_table = ON`, it needs only one handle per table (as opposed to 2).  But, Innodb disk footprint is usually 2x-3x bigger than MyISAM.
- It is an old wives tale that MyISAM is faster.  After I see more info on your system (see Comments), I will think about whether your case is an exception.  What version of MySQL?
- `ulimit -n`, or [systemd LimitNOFILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#useful-systemd-options), It feeds to MySQL's `open_files_limit`, which is a cap for table_open_cache`.
- That value of `1024000` may cause other problems.
- Do you ever purge old data?  Or is that "173 partitions" a growing number?
- How much RAM do you have?
- Are your queries usually in the 'latest' partition?  Or are they randomly scattered?  (This can have a big impact on performance.)
- I don't see any secondary indexes; do you only fetch by time?
- `DOUBLE` (8 bytes) is rarely a useful datatype, especially for measurements.  Consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes, ~7 significant digits).
- MySQL has already deprecated MyISAM; MariaDB may follow suit some day.
- That sounds like an average of 3K rows per partition?  (1-3KB per row, 3000*173 partitions, total of 1-2 TB.)  I suggest that it is hardly worth partitioning, especially if the `PRIMARY KEY` is the only index you have.  Are there 500 different sensors you are tracking on each of 3000 devices or vehicles (or whatever) that you are tracking?  No partitioning, no multiple tables, simply `PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, datetime)` will be much simpler and probably more efficient.
- I assume the data comes in ~chronologically for each of the 3000 items.  In a single-table solution, with the PK above, there would be 3000 hot spots.  This is not a problem for performance problem.  If fact it would be more efficient in InnoDB due to the layout of the data on disk.
- Sounds like you have lots of Summary tables, too.  You don't need a separate summary table for each granularity.  Instead, have one, maybe two.  Perhaps "day" and "month".  For in-between things (hour, week), sum up the values in the appropriate summary table.  More discussion: [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)
- `PARTITION BY TO_DAYS(...)` (or `TO_SECONDS`) for the single table would provide a single (not 3000) `DROP` + `REORGANIZE` every day (or week) to purge data older than 3 years.  More:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- InnoDB organizes the data based on the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- MyISAM tacks new rows onto the end of the table until there have been deletes.  THen it give preference to filling in the holes.  This may lead to a very fragmented table.  MyISAM requires an extra index lookup for the PK that InnoDB avoids.

Comment: It was made the default in 5.5 in 2010 where it was already faster. The only time I can recall MyISAM having a measurable advantage was in the 5.0 days, or around 2005.

Comment: @tadman - Let's hope he is not running 5.0.

Comment: I'll join in hoping as I have a lingering concern this might be some museum-grade installation of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is (currently) MariaDB 10.3.28, but I have been running similar setups using "modern" (current version) of MySQL for the last ~5ish years.

Comment: Re: partitioning, I attempt to "crystal ball" it when we head into a truly production environment.  Typically am looking for about 3 years.  Previous experiences with database sizing (and total partitions I can get away with) seems to have led me to this range (~175) of partitions.  Hence my math then leads to ~1 weeks of data per partition.

Comment: I do not believe RAM to be a problem, as I'm seeing the same behavior whether it's a small dev environment (like this test case, 8 GB of RAM) or on our production side (128 GB of RAM).  To better address where the queries are taking place, it's really in the current "time period".  As mentioned in the other comment, I kind of pave a runway of partitions for ~3 years.  So at the beginning of the test campaign I'm primarily working at the front of these partitions, towards the end I'm in the later partitions.

Comment: And yes, all queries (both insertion and select/read) are entirely time-based.  I do need millisecond resolution, hence the usage of the composite key (whole seconds Unix epoch, and millisecond counter).  There is not a secondary index in use.

Comment: Also, maybe it is time that I re-experiment with InnoDB ... I admittedly made a decision long ago (using older documentation) that only MyISAM could give me the fastest read speed.  I really appreciate all of your help, and yield to your suggestion!!!  Thanks!

Comment: 10.3: GA: May 2018; EOL: May 2023

Comment: @user3120127 - I added several paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks again for this summary, you have given me lots to think about.  Things have grown quite a bit since the (comparatively small) beginnings of this project.  I am going to re-evaluate as you suggested.